# How to filter entries by slug in url segment?

Tags: entries, slug

I want to return entries in the news section, except the one that has a slug the matches url segment 2.

I've tried:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('news').slug(not craft.request.getSegment(2)).limit(6) %}...
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('news').slug('and, not craft.request.getSegment(2)').limit(6) %}...
```

But neither work - *all* entries are returned.

What's the right syntax please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is just some confusion between what should be a string or not. From the docs on [Parameter Value Syntax](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#parameter-value-syntax):

> To exclude entries with a given value, you must pass in a string, prefixed with not

To that end the following should work for your example:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('news').slug('not ' ~ craft.request.getSegment(2)).limit(6) %}...
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)